# Defining a formula using FO+TC

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Define a signature Σ and an FO+TC formula ϕ over Σ, such that:

- there is no infinite structure satisfying ϕ
- for every even natural number n>0 there is a structure of size n satisfying ϕ
- for every odd natural number m>0 there is no structure of size m satisfying ϕ.

FO+TC is First-order logic with transitive closure, for example you can have formula $\phi := TC{a,b}(b = a + a)(x,y)$
which can be translated to $y = 2^n * x$

using transitive closure we can define the natural numbers or define a path in graph

Comment: What is "FO+TC"?

Comment: First-order Logic with Transitive closure

Comment: I know first-order logic, but what does "with transitive closure" mean in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_logic_and_computational_complexity

Comment: x @Yan: That link does not give sufficient details to enable someone to answer the question. To make your question self-contained, please ***edit the question*** to add a description of the operators/constructions your logic has in addition to ordinary first-order-logic, and their semantics.

Comment: done, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities. For example, you could decide that your structure should be a cyclic group of even order.

- "Group" is a well-known (finitely axiomatized) first-order theory.
- Requiring an element of order 2 will prevent it from having odd order, by Lagrange's theorem.
- And your transitive-closure operator allows you to express that there's an element that generates the group (by positive powers only).

---

Alternatively, your structure could be a strongly connected bipartite directed graph where every node has out-degree 1 (which is to say, a cycle of even length -- though that needs to be proved).

Or it could be a discrete linear order with maximal and minimal element where every two elements are a finite distance from each other, and structures are forced to have even size by a separate relation that pairs the elements up two by two.